# MySQL Access denied on grant all privileges with an admin user

Tags: mysql

When I try to grant privileges to a user with an admin user I get this error message:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `awesomeproject`.* TO 'awesomeproject'@'localhost';
```

Result:

```
ERROR 1044 (42000): Access denied for user 'mygoodadmin'@'localhost' to database 'awesomeproject'
```

If I check the current user's privileges with this command:

```sql
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'mygoodadmin'@'localhost';
```

I get this result:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for mygoodadmin@localhost                           |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'mygoodadmin'@'localhost'            |
| GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON `%`.* TO 'mygoodadmin'@'localhost' |
+------------------------------------------------------------+
```

What I missed?

Comment: I do not see WITH GRANT OPTION.

Answer (score 2):

The solution is based on [Akina](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10138734/akina)'s comment:

```sql
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'dcms_central'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

The additional information:

`*.*` is the good way, not this one:

```
`%`.*
```